# Error while deploying NextJS on AWS for serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js, serverless

When I tried to deploy my NextJS app to AWS with serverless framework.

In my next JS app directory, I ran the command npx serverless

and got the following error -

```
    $ npx serverless

  error:
  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected:
  - The root value has an unexpected property, target, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, future, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
warn  - The `target` config is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deprecated-target-config
error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: yarn add --dev eslint
Failed to compile.

./pages/_app.tsx:3:29
Type error: Cannot find module '@mui/material' or its corresponding type declarations.

  1 | import "../styles/globals.css";
  2 | 
> 3 | import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
    |                             ^
  4 | import { StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
  5 | import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
  6 | import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\Users\bruno.cruz\Documents\INGRESSE-COM\repo\finance-web\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:11661)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (C:\Users\bruno.cruz\Documents\INGRESSE-COM\repo\finance-web\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12599)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\bruno.cruz\Documents\INGRESSE-COM\repo\finance-web\.env
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
    at makeError (C:\Users\bruno.cruz\.serverless\components\registry\npm\@sls-next\serverless-component@1.18.0\node_modules\@sls-next\serverless-component\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (C:\Users\bruno.cruz\.serverless\components\registry\npm\@sls-next\serverless-component@1.18.0\node_modules\@sls-next\serverless-component\node_modules\execa\index.js:114:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build',
  command: 'node_modules/.bin/next build',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: 'info  - Loaded env from C:\\Users\\bruno.cruz\\Documents\\INGRESSE-COM\\repo\\finance-web\\.env\n' +
    'info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin\n' +
    'info  - Linting and checking validity of types...',
  stderr: 'warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: \n' +
    '  - The root value has an unexpected property, target, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, future, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).\n' +
    '\n' +
    'See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config\n' +
    'warn  - The `target` config is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.\n' +
    'See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deprecated-target-config\n' +
    'error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: yarn add --dev eslint\n' +
    'Failed to compile.\n' +
    '\n' +
    './pages/_app.tsx:3:29\n' +
    "Type error: Cannot find module '@mui/material' or its corresponding type declarations.\n" +
    '\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 1 | \x1B[39m\x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m \x1B[32m"../styles/globals.css"\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +  
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 2 | \x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m\x1B[31m\x1B[1m>\x1B[22m\x1B[39m\x1B[90m 3 | \x1B[39m\x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m { \x1B[33mCssBaseline\x1B[39m } \x1B[36mfrom\x1B[39m \x1B[32m"@mui/material"\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m   | \x1B[39m                            \x1B[31m\x1B[1m^\x1B[22m\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 4 | \x1B[39m\x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m { \x1B[33mStyledEngineProvider\x1B[39m\x1B[33m,\x1B[39m \x1B[33mThemeProvider\x1B[39m } \x1B[36mfrom\x1B[39m \x1B[32m"@mui/material/styles"\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 5 | \x1B[39m\x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m type { \x1B[33mAppProps\x1B[39m } \x1B[36mfrom\x1B[39m \x1B[32m"next/app"\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[0m \x1B[90m 6 | \x1B[39m\x1B[36mimport\x1B[39m { appWithTranslation } \x1B[36mfrom\x1B[39m \x1B[32m"next-i18next"\x1B[39m\x1B[33m;\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\n' +
    '> Build error occurred\n' +
    'Error: Call retries were exceeded\n' +
    '    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\\Users\\bruno.cruz\\Documents\\INGRESSE-COM\\repo\\finance-web\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\jest-worker\\index.js:1:11661)\n' +
    '    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (C:\\Users\\bruno.cruz\\Documents\\INGRESSE-COM\\repo\\finance-web\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\jest-worker\\index.js:1:12599)\n' +
    '    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)\n' +
    '    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {\n' +
    "  type: 'WorkerError'\n" +
    '}',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}

  11s » financeWebFront » Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The root value has an unexpected property, target, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, future, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
warn  - The `target` config is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deprecated-target-config
error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: yarn add --dev eslint
Failed to compile.

./pages/_app.tsx:3:29
Type error: Cannot find module '@mui/material' or its corresponding type declarations.

  1 | import "../styles/globals.css";
  2 | 
> 3 | import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
    |                             ^
  4 | import { StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
  5 | import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
  6 | import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\Users\bruno.cruz\Documents\INGRESSE-COM\repo\finance-web\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:11661)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (C:\Users\bruno.cruz\Documents\INGRESSE-COM\repo\finance-web\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12599)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\bruno.cruz\Documents\INGRESSE-COM\repo\finance-web\.env
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
```

I'm using aws configure to set my AWS credentials.

My serverless.yml file is as follow,

```
myNextApplication:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.18.0"
```

How should I deploy my app to AWS cloud with a serverless framework?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did you got any solution for this? Did you also got this error. Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js. while deploying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the missing dependency `npm i @mui/material` or `yarn add @mui/material`. That should fix it. Also, check your `next.config.js` file. It seems you are adding some things there which do not belong.

More so, to deploy to AWS, just use [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js/). Read the docs to see how to set up with Next.js. It's very simple. Just deploy your code to github, connect to your repo via Amplify and then allow it to build your project for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically serverless nextjs is dead and the newest version are not supported

If AWS lambda is your unique option then try reverting the nextjs version to 11.x